# Website not loading on iOS Safari

Tags: ios, safari

I am developing a custom Wordpress site for a client that is working fine on desktop browsers and Android (Chrome and Firefox). However, when I try to load the site on an iPhone using Safari all I see is a white screen and the spinning loader gif at the top of the display. It remains in that state without displaying an error or any other changes.

I have never experienced an issue like this before. The dev site is deployed on a subdomain of my personal website. It can be viewed here: http://syndicate.korynorthrop.com/

This is a re-design/update of an existing site. I created a child theme of the original site's theme.

Comment: doesn't work on safari for mac either (macOS 10.11.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like its a problem with your bootstrap. Try using the bootstrap cdn or resolve whatever issue is going on with the host.[image]

Comment: Nice find! I was still able to load the site on my computer because I was running my local server and thus able to access the `bootstrap.min.js` file that was requested. Thank you!